# How to make a task factory?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

First, sorry for my english. Second, I looked for other solution (even "SemaphoreSlim", but When i used it, for all tasks was throwed "Task was cancelled" exception)

I am using MS SQL, `public static SqlConnection Connection`.

On this `Connection` I want to perform all Sql tasks, but these tasks can be started many times in this same time,

We have eg a function:

```
    private async object GetSomething()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE id = 1;", Connection))
            {
                await Connection.OpenAsync();

                var result = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();

                Connection.Close();

                return result;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Connection.Close();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

For example: in this same time, I want to execute this function two times

When first time `await Connection.OpenAsync();` will be used, there will be no problem, but when this function will be not finished yet, and

`await Connection.OpenAsync();` will be executed again, it will throw an error "Connection was not closed";

This is because `Connection.Close()` was not executed, because program was waiting for first object from `var result = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();`

So i Want to avoid this problem, by creating TasksManager, which will run all tasks as Queue, and return proper result to part of program where function was awaited. Is it possible?

I hope u understand what I want to do.

//what i did wrong, that u are unvoting this?

Comment: Solve the problem by simply not re-using the same connection.  Have these operations all create their own connection.  Then you have nothing to synchronize.  Note that a `TaskFactory` is not the appropriate way to synchronize access to that resource.  You don't have CPU bound work, (and even if you did, creating a custom task factory is almost never needed).  If you did want to synchronize access to the resource (which you don't) then `SemaphoreSlim` would indeed be the correct way to do it.

Comment: Just create a new connection instead of retaining it if your code can query multiple times the DB simultaneously. Sql connection already implements pooling so it will reuse the connections if they're reusable. Read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The sulution was so easy.. I didnt know that. 

Now my program works corectly, no bugs, no other events.

Thanks for link, it was very helpful :)